# Blurred overlay does not cover entire screen

Tags: ios, swift, frontend, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I'm trying to display a blurred background over a ViewController that contains a UITableView and is displayed modally. **But I can't seem to get the blur effect to cover the entire screen, specifically the Navigation and Status Bars.** Below is a screenshot of the blur effect covering the area below the Navigation Bar but not above it -- this happens when I set the frame of the UIVisualEffectView to **view.bounds**. (Note: The blur effect is designed to be displayed at the same time as the title screen w/ keyboard, and the title screen has a clear + non-opaque background to accommodate this blur effect.)

[image]

Interestingly, when I set the frame of the UIVisualEffectView to **view.frame** (rather than view.bounds), the blur effect only covers about 2/3rds of the area that view.bound covers. Not sure why it's doing this.

Below is what I have in my code. As you can see, when the 'Done' button is pressed, the app generates the ActionViewController (the title screen) along with the blurred background which is called through a delegate method.

```
@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = ActionViewController()
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.overlayBlurredBackgroundView()
    vc.delegate = self
}

extension PreviewViewController: ActionViewControllerDelegate {
    func overlayBlurredBackgroundView() {
        let blurredBackgroundView = UIVisualEffectView()
        blurredBackgroundView.frame = view.bounds
        blurredBackgroundView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterialDark)
        view.addSubview(blurredBackgroundView)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, what Muhammad suggested should work. The reason your code crashes could be you are attempting to add the constraints first before adding the `blurView` to your view as a subview. The key phrase is:

> they have no common ancestor.

Don't do that. Always add your subview before constraining it.

---

Lastly, one easy way to achieve what you want to achieve is to just toggle your navigationBar's visibility whenever you present your transparent screen (the one with the keyboard) and then put the navigationBar back to visible when you're done. Like so:

```
func overlayBlurredBackgroundView() {
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
  
    let blurredBackgroundView = UIVisualEffectView()
    //blurredBackgroundView.frame = view.bounds
    blurredBackgroundView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterialDark)
    view.addSubview(blurredBackgroundView)
  
    blurredBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blurredBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    blurredBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    blurredBackgroundView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    blurredBackgroundView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

}
```

and then putting it back when you're removing it:

```
func removeBlurredBackgroundView() {
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview.isKind(of: UIVisualEffectView.self) {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the blur overlay view in the presented view controller instead of presenting view controller i.e. `ActionViewController`. As far as frame is concern, just add right constraint and it will be layout automatically (no need to set frame) for example if you want your blur view to cover the entire screen you can add these constraints.

In the `viewDidLoad` function of `ActionViewController` call this function

```
func addOverlayBlurredBackgroundView() {
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView()
    blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterialDark)
    self.view.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)

    blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    blurView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    blurView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    blurView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad. I am indeed putting the blur overlay in the presented view controller (i.e. PreviewViewController, not ActionViewController). When I add the constraints as you suggest, the app crashes and displays the message "Unable to activate constraint with anchors because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."

Comment: yes! i am suggesting you to put the blur view in the `ActionViewController` . From your code i can see that you are presenting `ActionViewController` then adding blur view in the preview view controller. The preview view controller is in the navigation controller and whatever you add on its view it will remain below the navigation bar.

Comment: I see. I tried putting in the blur view as a frame within the loadView function in the ActionViewController, but it doesn't seem to be appearing. Any suggestion on how to do this? Also, using constraints will continue to generate the error that I mentioned previously.