iOS adding a blur view does not cover the whole screen on Max models
when I add a blur to the background view like this:
 let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
 let blurredView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
 blurredView.frame = self.bounds
 self.backgroundView?.addSubview(blurredView)

on pro max models, it does not cover the whole screen:


Please provide more information. We don't know how you used backgroundView and your subview. In theory, if your subview is correctly aligned to fill the entire screen space, it should work. Try placing your code inside the viewDidLoad function of a view controller, and you will see that it works.
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurredView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurredView.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(blurredView)

closing question because another answer works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716766/blurred-overlay-does-not-cover-entire-screen
